# Write a text file in Appveyor script

Tags: command-line, appveyor

I have a problem when writing a simple text file with appveyor. Here is the simple script:

```
version: 1.0.{build}-{branch}

shallow_clone: true

environment:
  matrix:
    - APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE: Visual Studio 2017
      TOOLSET: msvc-14.1
      ARCH: x86_64

install:

build: off

test_script:
  - echo ^<Where are my symbols^> > hello.txt
  - more hello.txt
```

This leads to an error in the console:

```
Build started
Fetching repository commit (2be7d4b)...OK
Total: 274 bytes in 1 files
echo ^<Where are my symbols^> > hello.txt
Command exited with code 1
```

I have tried the commands in on desktop but everything is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This escape symbol will not work this way because internally we use `call` before your cmd when executing command from the custom PowerShell host.

Workarounds:

- Use PowerShell

`test_script:
  - ps: Set-Content -Value "<Where are my symbols>" -Path .\hello.txt
  - more hello.txt`

- Check-in `.cmd` file with your command which uses `^` escape symbol and run it.